# ConnectivityManager to verify internet connection

Tags: android, package

Hi all I need to verify if my device is currently connected to internet or not and so I wrote this class that uses a `ConnectivityManager` to check:

```
public boolean checkInternetConnection() {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

works great, because right now the method is in a class in the main package (`com.App`), but how should I change the code to make it work in a class defined in `com.App.Utility` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
package com.app.utility;

  public class Utilities {

    public static final boolean CheckInternetConnection(Context context) {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;

      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The only issue with using getActiveNetworkInfo() is that there are a number of situations where is will not correctly detect connectivity. For example if the mobile network is disabled on a phone but wifi is available then the active network may still be counted as the mobile network and therefore return false.

An alternative is:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfoMob = cm.getNetworkInfo(cm.TYPE_MOBILE);
    NetworkInfo netInfoWifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(cm.TYPE_WIFI);
    if ((netInfoMob != null || netInfoWifi != null) && (netInfoMob.isConnectedOrConnecting() || netInfoWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thx Alan H!

The if condition may cause NPE when one of netInfoMob and netInfoWifi is null but the other not.

This one works for me:

```
netInfoMobile != null && netInfoMobile.isConnectedOrConnecting() ||
netInfoWifi != null && netInfoWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this code works.

```
public static boolean checkNetwork(Context context) {
   context = context;
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if ((connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) != null && connManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected())
            || (connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) != null && connManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            .isConnected())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In any code section you want to use checkNetwork() . You can try it .       if (Constant.getInstance().checkNetwork(getApplicationContext()))
 {
 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } 
 else 
 {
 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, Constant.NETWORK_PROBLEAM, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check with `kotlin`.

```
 fun checkInternetConnection(context Context) {
     connectivityManager : ConnectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?

     if(connectivityManager.activeNetwork) {
         return true
     } else {
         return false
     }
 }
```