# How to check for internet connectivity before making a request

Tags: java, android

I have this usual code to make HTTP requests to the server.

```
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      ...
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(finalUri.toURI());
        httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");

        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
```

This works fine when there is internet connectivity. But when there is no internet connectivity the code just wait for long time at `httpclient.execute(httpGet);` until it times out and throwing exception and crashing the application.

```
01-10 15:17:48.612  20692-20806/com.somepackage.somepackage  E/EXCEPTION﹕ Unable to resolve host "myapi.myhost.com": No address associated with hostname
```

For the exception I can catch `UnknownHostException e` and handle it. But still is there a way to know it prehand that internet connectivity is missing?

Comment: have added http:// infront of your url??

Comment: For checking if the user is currently connected, look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7071617/2857385

Answer (score 1):

You can use *NetworkInfo* for the purpose.

```
private boolean checkNetworkConnection() {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo == null || !networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
public boolean IsInternetAvailable(Context context)
{

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
            = (ConnectivityManager) (context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of checking internet connection status with connection type:

```
public boolean getConnectionStatus(Context context) {
int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI||conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
  return true;
} 
else{
   return false
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check this like below.You can check this by standard `java.net.URLConnection` class simply.

```
 try{
     URLConnection urlConnection = finalUri.openConnection();
     urlConnection.connect();
 }
 catch(Exception ex){
    //No connection to finalUri
    // return your error code for no connection
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new method inside your current `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
        boolean available = false;
        /** Getting the system's connectivity service */
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        /** Getting active network interface  to get the network's status */
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(networkInfo !=null && networkInfo.isAvailable())
            available = true;

        /** Returning the status of the network */
        return available;
    }
```

And here is how to use it. You can use it inside `onCreate()` method:

```
if (isNetworkAvailable() == true){ // if network is available
   // do your thing here
   ...
}else{ // "else" means that the network is not available
   // do your thing here
   ...
}
```